# How to detect if the first letter does not contain a hyphen

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to detect: if first letter is not a hyphen, then prepend element. This is my attempt:

```
$('.post-category-label .item:first-letter(:not(:contains("-")))').insertBefore('<span class="item">Uncategorized</span>');
```

However, Chrome console says `:first-letter` is not supported by jQuery.

How do I make this work?

EDIT: changed `.prepend()` to `insertBefore()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using a JQuery selector, you can filter out the ones that contain a hyphen as the first letter.

```js
$('.post-category-label .item').filter((index, item) => item.innerHTML.split('')[0] !== '-').prepend('<span class="item">Uncategorized </span>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="post-category-label">
  <span class="item">- test</span><br>
  <span class="item">other test</span><br>
  <span class="item">third test</span><br>
  <span class="item">- final test</span><br>
</span>
```